# Stripe one time payments allow promotion code

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am going to implement a promotion code with a one-time payment. Stripe has announcement to use "allow_promotion_code=true" parameter on one time payments.

But something wrong with promotion input. Sometimes promotion code input didn't show up. Is there a bug for stripe or did I miss something?

```json
  "id": "cs_test_b1IjCh7A8FGNDekAWtQZR93USCT2G3dxRe9zyLcGg7Qy3Ddt8yxxxx",
  "object": "checkout.session",
  "allow_promotion_codes": true,
  "amount_subtotal": 4140,
  "amount_total": 4140,
  "billing_address_collection": "required",
  "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8000/checkout?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
  "client_reference_id": null,
  "currency": "gbp",
  "customer": null,
  "customer_email": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "locale": null,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "mode": "payment",
  "payment_intent": "pi_1HxdH1CZvxxxxxx",
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "payment_status": "unpaid",
  "setup_intent": null,
  "shipping": null,
```

Comment: We're going to need more information to be able to help. Does this work for you sometimes but not always? What's the difference in the requests when it does do what you expect? Can we access an online demo in test mode to try this ourselves?

Comment: Yes, same requests different returns I have got. Of course you can https://staging-m9.1984.design/

Comment: In my testing of various quantities and shipping options I always saw the promo code field. What steps are you following to get the result of no promo code?

Comment: I don't see the promo code neither in the checkout session completed webhook in a one time payment. Any idea?