# how to setup promo code, for stripe checkout one time payment

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi I setup in stripe test mode and customer facing coupon code, called "SAVE1"
im using stripe checkout for one time (non-recurring) payment.
I enabled `allow_promotion_codes: true` and i see it in the checkout page.
but when i tried the coupon code, it says invalid.
the way i setup the coupon in stripe dashboard is to allow all users all the time for any amount of time.

But i noticed every  single tutorial and video for stripe coupons is for recurring payments.

is there a reason why i cannot  get it to work for one time  payment?

aka, 5 years later, is this still true
?? https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Stripe-not-allow-for-coupon-discount-codes-to-be-used-for-one-time-payments

its similar to this [Stripe one time payments allow promotion code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293169/stripe-one-time-payments-allow-promotion-code), but my issue is one step after that, since i can see the textbox to insert the coupon code in stripe checkout page.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it doesn't work only when I am trying to apply 100% discount. When I use coupon with 50% discount, it works fine.

There is a doc about the one time payment discounts btw.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts

Comment: Seems as if making coupon for 97% off, works.

Comment: Indeed, adding 100% (or absolute amount equal to the product amount) does not work. Adding a 99% reduction does work however (but might fail if your bank does not allow small amount).

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a Promotion Code for the coupon and then it should work: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/discounts#creating-promotion-codes